# How to read/fetch data from Oracle SQL database using PowerShell Core?

Tags: windows, powershell, installation, database, oracle-database

I have been researching on this for a couple of days but have been going in circles here.

I need to write a script that fetches the data from Oracle db and do something with the data. In my script I will have to fetch data multiple times. My machine has the `SQLDeveloper-21.4.3` which I got from installing `InstantClient-Basic-Windows-21.3.0`. I use the SQL Developer to connect to the db which is on another machine; this is how I can look into tables, views etc. of the db.

Secondly, this script will be hosted on another server that runs Windows-Server-2012-R2. I am just using my machine to write the script because I cannot use the server to do this. Therefore, I am looking for a solution that requires minimum amount of installing.

Thirdly, we do not have Oracle commercial license. This Oracle db I am trying to access is on the machine installed by a third party that installed some instruments. This company uses Oracle as they collect data on the instruments installed.

I was hoping the solution would be something similar to invoking connection to MS SQL where I downloaded module that gave cmdlets to connect to the MS SQL.

Oracle does have `Oracle Modules for PowerShell` but neither have I found information on how to use them nor have I understood the little information provided by Oracle on this. For this to work one of the requirement is:

> A configuration file and key pair used for signing API requests, with
> the public key uploaded to Oracle Cloud using Oracle Cloud
> Infrastructure Console. Only the user calling the API should possess
> the private key.

I don't know the heck Oracle is talking about here. Like, what is this configuration file, where is it? Where would I get the key pair from for signing API request. What is Oracle Infrastructure Console, where do I get it from? You get the idea. Link: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/powershell.htm

Therefore, I went the .DLL route.

This is what I have done so far:

I installed `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core -Version 3.21.61` from NuGet. Unzipped the package and moved the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` to the location of my script. The code is:

```
$OracleDLLPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\CNC_File_Transfer_VSCode\Fastems_NicNet\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
    $datasource = " (DESCRIPTION = 
                    (ADDRESS = 
                    (PROTOCOL = TCP)
                    (HOST  = 10.50.61.9)(PORT = 1521))
                    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER =  DEDICATED)
                    (SERVICE_NAME = Fa1)
                    (FAILOVER_MODE = (TYPE = SELECT)
                    (METHOD =  BASIC)
                    (RETRIES = 180)
                    (DELAY = 5))))"
    $username = "username"
    $password = "password"
    $queryStatment = "SELECT [PROG_TYPE] FROM NC_PROGRAMS FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY" 
    #Load Required Types and modules
    Add-Type -Path $OracleDLLPath 
    Import-Module SqlServer
    Write-Host $queryStatment
    #Create the connection string
    $connectionstring = 'User Id=' + $username + ';Password=' + $password + ';Data Source=' + $datasource 
    #Creates a data adapter for the command
    $da = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter($cmd);
    #The Data adapter will fill this DataTable
    $resultSet = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    #Only here the query is sent and executed in Oracle 
    [void]$da.fill($resultSet)
    #Close the connection
    $con.Close()
    WRITE-HOST $resultSet
```

This gives an error though:

```
Add-Type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve 
the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

I am new to programming in general. I would really appreciate if someone could provide detailed steps on resolving this. Thanks in advance.